# Preserved flowers in epoxy resin

Tags: flowers

I want to cast flowers in resin. The problem is that everyone is casting dried flowers in order to prevent the moisture from fresh flowers evaporating while the resin is curing and I need to cast fresh flower. I tought of freeze dried flowers but could not find any company that could do it in my country nor online shop where to buy in europe. I am thinking of castin stabilized roses which are dehydrated first and the soaked with glycerin, propyl glycol and som dyes for colors. I wonder  if the glycerin with propyl glycol will evaporate with the higher temperature during the resin curing process.